# Is it ok to have many Entity Data Models in your project or should you always have only one?

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, datamodel

We have a big database with hundreds of tables.
We are just beginning to use Entity Framework 4.

Should we build one huge Data Model for it or divide it into many Data Models based on some criteria?

Answer (score 1):

My colleagues and I tried out the "One True Data Context" back in the Linq2Sql days. We found it quickly became awkward to maintain. So we've now opted for lots of smaller "task specific" contexts, which we are finding is working much better.

Having said that there is no "right" way. Go with whatever suits your particular situation and how you are going to use the context(s).

So, it's another classic **it depends** answer I'm afraid.

PS - Our database has about 300 tables in it. Of which 150 or so were in our model.

PPS - We're moving towards code first now, which I personally much prefer to the designer.

Comment: We currently have a single entity model and it covers different 'sub-systems' which is becoming painful to maintain.  I wonder if CodeFirst would help with some of the pain.  We only have 30-40 tables currently but I expect it to grow to at least 100.

Comment: the nice thing with code first is that your config is in code (obviously) which means version control just works. I've lost count of the number of times I had to merge xml. The designer used to jiggle the order of things around which made it 100 times worse. I've written a couple of blog articles on code first configuration. Having all my config classes automatically loaded makes life just that little bit simpler. ie - one less thing to worry about